# .NET MVC 4: Displaying an image from Image object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a .NET MVC 4 application that stores images in a database. I am retrieving the images like this:

```
byte[] imageBytes = dbObject.dbImage;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

So now I've got the image, and I just want to display it in an MVC view. I can't figure out how to do this without saving the image locally, which seems crazy. I've read other suggestions about creating a handler, but that seems like overkill for such a simple task.

How can I display this image in a view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the bytes to Base64 and embed it in a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Beware that this will not work in IE < 8.

Comment: Definitely piqued my interest! In the wikipedia page it mentions "the encoded data is downloaded every time the containing documents are re-downloaded". Does this mean there is *no caching* or just that there is no caching of the image itself separately? And is that behavior web-server specific?

Comment: @RGraham: `data:` URIs are part of the document containing them, just like other content or URLs.  They are subject to the same caching policy as the rest of the document.  However, documents are usually less cacheable than images.  This depends entirely on your server-side caching configuration.

Comment: Awesome. You definitely don't need it, but you get my +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an Action which returns an image, e.g.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetImage(int imageId) {
  byte[] imageBytes = dbObject.dbImage;
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
  return File(ms, "image/png", "myimage.png");
}
```

**View**

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "MyController", new { imageId = 1 })" alt="MyImage" />
```

Comment: My image isn't displaying when I do this. In fact, it doesn't seem like "GetImage" is even called, i.e. I put a breakpoint in there and it's never reached.

Comment: @JamesHarpe: It would be called as a separate HTTP request by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`FileResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

*Controller*

```
public ActionResult Images() {
    byte[] imageBytes = dbObject.dbImage;
    return File(imageBytes, "image/png");
}
```

*View*

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Images", "Controller")"  />
```

Comment: My image isn't displaying when I do this. Placing a breaking in the Images method shows that the method is never called.